# Custom Taxonomy get_terms

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am trying to fill up a couple of dropdown lists using a custom taxonomy according to level. I would like to add also the term fields but unfortunately the get_terms() method is returning the whole taxonomy not up to the level I set in the $args. Any idea why this is happening?

```
    function get_all_children(){
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
        $p = $_REQUEST['parent'];
        $l = $_REQUEST['level'];
                 
       
          $args = array(
            'show_option_none' => ' ',
            'child_of' => $p,
            'hide_if_empty' => true,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'depth' => 1,
            'echo' => 0,
            'hierarchical'    =>  1,
            'name' => $l,

        );   
        

        $ddl = get_terms_dropdown($args,$l,$p);
       echo $ddl;

    }

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_get_all_children', 'get_all_children');
add_action('wp_ajax_get_all_children', 'get_all_children');
```

In the beginning $p is set to null for level 1 category.

```
   function get_terms_dropdown($args,$l,$p){

 $myterms = get_terms(  array('taxonomy' => 'collection', $args) );
 $output ="<select id='".$l."' name='".$l."'>";
 
    foreach($myterms as $term){
        $term_name =$term->name;
        $term_id = $term->term_id;
        $term_group = $term->term_group;
        $term_slug = $term->slug;
        $term_var1 = types_render_termmeta( "variation-1", array( "term_id" => $term_id ) ); 
        $term_var2 = types_render_termmeta( "variation-2", array( "term_id" => $term_id ) ); 
        $term_var3 = types_render_termmeta( "variation-3", array( "term_id" => $term_id ) ); 
        if($term_var3!=null){
            $output .="<option value='".$term_id."'>".$term_name.'/'.$term_var1.'/'.$term_var2.'/'.$term_var3."</option>";            
        }else if ($term_var2!=null){
            $output .="<option value='".$term_id."'>".$term_name.'/'.$term_var1.'/'.$term_var2."</option>";            
        }else if ($term_var1!=null){
            $output .="<option value='".$term_id."'>".$term_name.'/'.$term_var1."</option>";            
        }else{
            $output .="<option value='".$term_id."'>".$term_name."</option>";            
        }
        
    
    }
    $output .="</select>";
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: The documentation for `get_terms` refers to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/ for the allowed arguments, but for example your `show_option_none`, and probably more importantly, `depth`, I do not even see mentioned there.

Comment: The `$args` should be merged into the array in `get_terms` rather than be appended as another array.